# Find an upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ such that: $T(a+bx+cx^2) = (a+b) + (b-c)x + (a+b+c)x^2$
>   $B=\{1,x+1, x^2+1\}$. Find a basic $C$ such that ${[T]_{B \to C}}^{}$ is an upper triangular matrix.

Use $T$ for each term in the basis, $B$:

$$\begin{array}{l}
 T(1) = 1 + {x^2} \\ 
 T(x + 1) = 2(1 + {x^2}) + x \\ 
 T({x^2} + 1) = 2(1 + {x^2}) - x - 1 \\ 
 \end{array}$$

Apparently,
We get that $C = \{ 1 + {x^2},x,1\}$ is basis which satisfying out needs.

$$\begin{array}{l}
 {[T(1)]_c} = (1,0,0) \\ 
 {[T(x + 1)]_c} = (2,1,0) \\ 
 {[T({x^2} + 1)]_c} = (2, - 1, - 1) \\ 
 \end{array}$$

**I have two questions:**

1. How could I possibly figure it out?
2. Is there another way solving it? I thought about calculating ${[T]_{B \to E}},{[T]_{E \to C}}$ (here, $E$ is the standard basis). Would that be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation $T$ is invertible (just compute the determinant of its matrix in the standard basis, e.g.) so, given any basis $B = \{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ for the space, $T(B) = \{ Tb_1, Tb_1, Tb_3\}$ is also a basis for the space (do you see why?).

The matrix representation $[T]_{B \to T(B)}$ has a very simple form (what is it?) which is certainly upper-triangular.

Comment: In fact, now that I think about it, a bit more work shows that, if $T : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is any transformation, then there exist bases $B_n$ and $B_m$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ respectively such that $T$ takes the block-diagonal form $$[T]_{B_n \to B_m} = \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{1}_r && M \\
0 && \mathbf{0}_{m-r} \\
\end{pmatrix} $$
where $M$ is some $r \times (m-r)$ matrix.